# When is the beta version of Yoast SEO for Magento ready to test?

Tags: magento, yoast

Does anybody know when the Yoast SEO plugin for Magento 2 is ready to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment, the extension is only available in the beta phase. Before the release of version 1 at MEET Magento on 10 May in Utrecht.

Questions / Comments
If you have questions or comments? Please send an e-mail with your question or comment to yoast@maxserv.com.